# sessions + php + mysql + error

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, dreamweaver

i am creating a simple log in  form with using of the sessions but the problem that when i press the login it redirect me to **index.php**  but i need to go the **home.php**.  in the **logout.php** i destroy the session and i redirect to **index.php** but is someway the login button redirect me to the **index.php**  like ther were no a success in the login process how to fix this error i need so badly .

## index.php

```
<?php
require_once('global.php');

if(@$logged == 1)
{

    header("Location: home.php");
    exit();
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>index page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> this is the index page</h1>
<a href="login.php">Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

## global.php

```
<?php
session_start();
 require_once('connect.php'); 

// cheking if the sessions are set

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $session_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $session_pass = $_SESSION['password'];
    $session_id = $_SESSION['id'];

    //cheking if the member exist

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '".$session_id."' AND password = '".$session_pass."' LIMIT 1") or die("could not select memeber");
    $count_count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count_count > 0)
    {
      $logged = 1;
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
          $session_username = $row['username'];
      }
      $_SESSION['username'] = $session_username;
      $_SESSION['pass'] = $session_pass;
      $_SESSION['id'] = $session_id;        

    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: logout.php");
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    // if the user not loged in
    $logged = 0;

}

?>
```

## login.php

```
<?php
require_once('global.php');


$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    // error handling
    if((!$email) ||(!$pass))
    {
        $message = 'please insert both fields';

    }
    else
    {
        //secure data
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        $pass = sha1($pass);
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$pass."'LIMIT 1") or die("could not select data");
        $count_query = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($count_query == 0)
        {
            $message = 'your info was inccorrect';
        }
        else
        {
            //start SESSIONS
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {

                $username = $row['username'];
                $id = $row['id'];
            }
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

        }
        header("Location: home.php");
    }





}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>login to membership website </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> login to my website</h1>
<p><?php print("$message"); ?></p>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email adress" /><br />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

## home.php

```
<?php
 require_once('global.php');
if($logged == 0)
{

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>this the home page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

## logout.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

session_destroy();
/*
if(session_is_registered('username'))
{

    echo "you are loged in we can not log you out"; 
    exit();

}
*/
//else
//{

    header("Location: index.php");
//}


?>
```

Comment: Dont use @ its for suppressing errors

Comment: @ ScoRpion if i do not put the @ it display an error saying  UNdifine  index  logged in line .....

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking session with $_SESSION['username'], you don't need the logged variable.
you can allow the user to access the page when $_SESSION['username'] exists and if it doesn't redirect him to login page

Answer (score 0):

To be honest this is rather spagetti coded, a bit of a mess, but the problem is that login.php does not set $logged = true so login.php redirects to home.php and then home.php redirects to index.php

So try this

## Login.php

```
<?php
require_once('global.php');

$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    // error handling
    if((!$email) ||(!$pass)) {
        $message = 'please insert both fields';
    }
    else
    {
        //secure data
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        $pass = sha1($pass);
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$pass."'LIMIT 1") or die("could not select data");
        $count_query = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($count_query == 0) {
            $message = 'your info was inccorrect';
        } else {
            //start SESSIONS
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $username = $row['username'];
                $id = $row['id'];
            }
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            // NEW LINE
            $logged = 1;
        }
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
}
?>
```